# Wordpress 3.3 and Symfony 1.4 - trouble with includes

Tags: wordpress, symfony-1.4, administration

This has been asked many times but I haven't found my problem/solution yet, so I'm asking it:

I have a running Symfony 1.4 application and like to have wordpress in the /web/blog directory running next to symfony.

The weird thing is, the blog frontend is running perfectly but I can't access the administration and get an internal server error instead when going on /blog/wp-admin. All I see in appache's log files is:

```
[warn] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined  
function get_option() in /srv/www/vhosts/mysite/web/blog/wp-
admin/admin.php on line 32
```

I guess it has something to do with requiring and loading the needed files from the wp-admin directory. Though no error is thrown that a file doesn't exist or couldn't be found. Even if I go to line 31 and enter `echo "test"; exit;` just before the fatal error, it is executed and printed out. `var_dump(function_exists('get_option'))` is returning false.. The last test was this instead, to manually load functions.php: `require_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/functions.php');` - but it returns that `ABSPATH` and `WPINC` aren't even defined..

After logging in, I even see the Admin Bar on the Blog Frontend, but can't access any pages obviously. Though one error is shown in the apache logs when I watch the blog frontend (th html renderes to the end):

```
[warn] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function _get_cron_array() 
in /srv/www/vhosts/mysite/web/blog/wp-cron.php on line 47
```

very confusing.. could some kind of php setting on my server be responsible this?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, got the solution: 
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-301-apc-314-php-533-white-wp-adnmin-page

Turning `apc.include_once_override` from `1` to `0` did the job.